# Visual Studio Debugging: How to reference DLLs in another directory without manually copying to the project dir?

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

[This is specific to Visual Studio 2013 - my project requires this version.]

I have a C++ project which I can successfully build. However, the project comes with a number of DLLs which are not originally located in the project's Working Directory (by default `$ProjectDir` in the project's prefs). I would like to not have to move/copy those DLLs manually into the working dir. Is there a project property I can change, or other action I can take which will allow the debugger to see the needed DLLs? I don't need to step into/debug them, I just the debugger not to complain that it can't find them.

Comment: there is a setting called VC directories in the project properties

Comment: @pm100 I saw those - they are related to building, not debugging.

Comment: You could set the PATH, Project > Properties > Debugging, "Environment" setting.  Debugging it the exact same way it is going to run on the user's machine is highly advisable.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but unfortunately adding that dir to the Environment setting doesn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant You were actually right - I had the field formatted incorrectly. What worked for me was `PATH=$(ProjectDir)\..\..\;%PATH%`. Feel free to add as an answer and I will accept.